# C# how to fetch comments added by recipients while accepting or declining outlook appointments

Tags: c#, outlook

We are developing utility in C# to read outlook appointment, monitor whether recipient has accepted or rejected appointment etc. How to fetch comments added by recipients while accepting or declining outlook appointments

```
Application Myoutlook = new Application();
            NameSpace OutlookNS = Myoutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");


            Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = Myoutlook.Session.
                GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).
                Items.Find("[Subject]='" + trainingName + "'")
                as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

            string organizerName = appt.Organizer;

            if (appt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (appt != null)
            {
                foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in appt.Recipients)
                {
```

[image]

Comment: is it not the body of the message like everything else?

Comment: In Outlook, Recipient accepts or declined meeting requests. He sees option as to "edit response before sending". He write his own comments lets say why he is declined the requests or marked it as tentative etc. I want to read this response in C#.

Comment: I know, i use outlook every day. You have not answered the question.

Comment: There is no property like recip.Body or recip.Response. Appt.Body gives me what I have typed in meeting.

Comment: You need to open the responses not the original appointment

Comment: How to open the responses ? MailItem or Appointment Item does not contain recipient responses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void ReadOutlookResponse(string outlookAppointmentName)
    {
        Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
        string searchCriteria = "[Subject]='" + outlookAppointmentName + "'";

        // 1 - Returns Only 1
        MeetingItem item = null;
        Application myoutlook = new Application();
        item = myoutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items
            .Find("[Subject]='" + outlookAppointmentName + "'");
        string body = item.Body;

        // 2 - Loop and Return All
        folderItems = myoutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items;
        object resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria);
        while (resultItem != null)
        {
            if (resultItem is Outlook.MeetingItem)
            {
                item = resultItem as Outlook.MeetingItem;
                body = item.Body;
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem);
            resultItem = folderItems.FindNext();
        }
    }
```

Code can be enhanced to use GlobalAppointmentID. Above code will return meeting responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your "appt" variable containing the appointment has a body property, it contains the message.

So for example, if you sent me a message and I declined saying "Sorry washing my hair" the appt.body would contain my message.

Comment: Original Appointment i.e. appt.Body gives me below . Its what I entered in Appointment . "Agenda
Learn C# Development." OK ...How to open response ?

Comment: You should be reading the outlook responses! as demonstrated by the picture

Comment: Not really getting which Property or Method to be used. I am using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; On Google , I can see below comments- Responses s aren't stored on the Appointment object itself they would only be in the Acceptance/Decline message from each user if these messages are still in the Mailbox you would need to find them (based on the AppointmentID) and you could then get the information from the body of each message. eg if the messages are still in the Inbox you should be able to do

Comment: How to open  the responses ?

Comment: they are items in your mailbox - open them like anything else.- such as the response is demonstrated in your picture above, you opened a response..

Comment: ok. But they are which types of Items ? Because neither Mail Item nor Appointment Items contains responses.

Comment: MailItem item = null;
                Application Myoutlook = new Application();
                NameSpace OutlookNS = Myoutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            item = Myoutlook.Session.
                        GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).
                        Items.Find("[Subject]='" + "Accepted : C# 14May" + "'")
                    as Outlook.MailItem; // item returns NULL